A column in a MSSQL table is referred to by multiple physical column names
I have a springboot project using JPA. I have several model classes and MSSQL tables within this project.
@Getter
@Setter
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROMComparison")
public class IPromComparison {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "promCompId")
    private Integer promCompId;
    @Column(name = "hipExtrSd")
    private String hipExtrSd;

I'm using lombok for the getter, setter, entity and etc for data annotation.
The table for this model class is:

However whenever I try to start up the project I keep getting this error:
2024-06-19T14:44:15.180-04:00 ERROR 21716 --- [GaitLabApp] [JavaFX-Launcher] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Table [promcomparison] contains logical column name [hipExtrSd] referring to multiple physical column names: [hip_extrsd], [hip_extr_sd]

I ended up deleting the columns in the SQL Database and recreating them. Once I did that it resolved the error.
